# Pythonic way to middle slicing

Tags: python, numpy-slicing

I have an exercise which is requesting me to slice the three middle items of a list. I can use something like e.g.

```
    foods = ['pizza', 'salad', 'pasta', 'poison', 'meat', 'cake', 'chocolate']
    #slicing the middle three items in the list
    middle_foods = len(foods[:]) / 2
    middle_foods = int(middle_foods)
    middle_item = middle_foods + 1
    middle_item2 = middle_foods - 1
    
    print("The Three items from the middle of the list are:\n",
          foods[int(middle_item2)], foods[int(middle_foods)], foods[int(middle_item)]
          )
```

However, this is verbose and looks ugly. Is there a better way to write this using slices?

Comment: Do you know what slicing is? You've technically got slicing in your code, but in a place (`len(foods[:])`) where it's completely unnecessary and just wastes time. In the part where it could have been useful, you didn't use it.

Comment: This might be more of a [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question

Comment: yea i know what slicing is! 
Apologize for the confusion as I didn't ask it right  
Please next time suggest and show in code what I could have done better 
thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea, you can clean things up a bit though:

```
midx = len(foods) // 2
print(*foods[midx-1:midx+2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `index`, not `slice`. Try this:

```
foods = ['pizza', 'salad', 'pasta', 'poison', 'meat', 'cake', 'chocolate']
mid = len(foods)//2
foods[mid-1:mid+2] # this is slice
```